# Hiding field groups during registration

Tags: entities, users

I worked out a way to hide fields with field permission module on registration. But have not found a way to hide whole field groups. Is there a module or a particular API which can help with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with using hook_form_alter

You can do something like this:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'your_form_name') {
        //do what ever you want
        //$form is an array of form elements, to delete some of them you can just do:
        unset($form['your-element-name']);
        //or and I think it is more "drupal way" to do things you can hide an element using hide function, e.g.:
        hide($form['account']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following simple code:

```
field_group_hide_field_groups($form, array('group_advert_hidden'));
```

in hook_form_alter() or similar place.

In example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function foo_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    field_group_hide_field_groups($form, array('group_advert_hidden'));
}
```

Eventually you may try to use [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module to hide the fields, so empty group would be hidden, as [hiding field group are not supported yet](https://drupal.org/node/1161314).